# chef recipe to check the count of processes and monitor the number of open file descriptors

Tags: linux, chef-infra, metricbeat, sre

I am trying to update the `metricbeat_cookbook` to get some required info.

1. Monitor the number of Number of sessions and html5 client processes running each server. `ps -ef | grep -i html5 | wc -l`. This is the logic I need in the cookbook/recipe.

   ```rb
   execute 'ps -ef' do
     command 'ps -ef | grep -i html5 | wc -l'
     action :run
   end
   ```
2. Open file descriptors on linux server (this is the logic `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`)

   ```rb
   execute 'cat' do
     command 'cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr'
     action :run
   end
   ```

Any response/help is highly helpful to me and - Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome here. I have edited your question to be more meaningful for now. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also add some details like when you run this what happens and what you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you @seshadri_c for the response - I haven't ran the code yet as its in prod - and i am New to chef - so wanted to make sure if i am in the right direction - Does it Make sense what i have  wrote ? i mean the changes ? - and thank you for editing the question -

Comment: So the code you have written will run on the target. But what do you want to do with the result of the commands?

Comment: So we are trying to monitor some of the process on a bunch of servers and pass them to kibana Dashboard - as we have thousands of servers we are implementing the changes through cookbook

Comment: Alarms to be monitored :
Monitor CPU and Memory utilization of different services on schers(servers)
Services to be monitored:  WebKitNetworkProcess, html5client, WebKitWebProces, traffic_server
Total Sessions on each schers = Active Sessions + Suspended Sessions + Sleeping Sessions   
# ps -ef | grep -i html5 | wc -l

Comment: Total Sessions and html5 client processes running each schers should match .
Monitor the number of open file descriptors on schers:
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

Comment: @seshadri_c Thank you so much for the response - Do my  code look ok ??

Comment: I haven't used the metricbeat cookbook. So I don't know how to use it. But it seems you are not referring that cookbook anywhere in your recipe.

Comment: @seshadri_c Thank you - I  am trying to include/add up this code to the already existing cookbook i have - so that we can deploy on to the required server and then we can get the required output through a Kibana Dashboard